# on the Galois cohomology of reductive groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-theory, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ a simply connected group over an algebraically closed field.

$F=k((t))$ and $\mathcal{O}=k[[t]]$.

Let $\gamma\in G(\mathcal{O})\cap G(F)^{rs}$.

Let $E=k((t^{1/n}))$ with $n$ prime to the characteristic that splits $\gamma$, $\mathcal{O}_{E}$ his ring of integers and $\Gamma_{n}$ the galois group of the extension.
Let $I_{\gamma}$ the centralizer of $\gamma$ over $Spec(\mathcal{O})$

Do we have an injection

$H^{1}(\Gamma_{n}, I_{\gamma}(\mathcal{O}_{E}))\rightarrow H^{1}(\Gamma_{n}, G(\mathcal{O}_{E}))$?

The problem lies in the multiplicative part of $I_{\gamma}(\mathcal{O}_{E})$, so we may probably reduce the statement where $I_{\gamma}$ is a torus.

Comment: Tori are rarely simply connected, so I don't understand how the reduction should take place.

Comment: Since $\gamma$ is regular ss, $I_{\gamma}$ has $F$-fiber a torus (connected by Steinberg, as $G$ is simply connected). There's no way to arrange the $O$-group $I_{\gamma}$ is a torus. Assume char$(k)=p>0$. For *any* $k[[t]]$-group scheme $\mathcal{G}$ of finite type, $P:=\ker(\mathcal{G}(O_E) \rightarrow \mathcal{G}(k))$ is pro-$p$, so if $\mathcal{G}_0$ denotes the image of this reduction map then by a cocycle-twisting argument we see that $H^1(\Gamma_n,\mathcal{G}(O_E))\rightarrow {\rm{Hom}}(\Gamma_n,\mathcal{G}_0)$ is injective.  So the case char(k)>0 is done. But what's the motivation?

Comment: elements conjugated on $G(\mathcal{O}_{E})$ are conjugated on $G(\mathcal{O})$

Comment: how do you get a map from $H^{1}(\Gamma_{n},G(O_{E})\rightarrow Hom(\Gamma_{n},G_{0})$ and what's the link with $I_{\gamma}$?